# Restarted Process Output won't Read

Tags: c++, visual-c++, process

So I made a GUI in C++ which calls a child process every time a button is clicked twice. The StandardOutput is redirected, doesn't use ShellExecute.

I made a simple dummy process to test it, let's say dummy.exe, which basically just do this :

```
void() {
    printf("0");
}
```

And that's all. The process will exit itself after 0 is plotted.

The process is started when a button is clicked, which does this :

```
private: System::Void bt_getData_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    if (bt_getData->Text == "Get Data") {
        proc->Start();  
        bt_getData->Text = "Stop";
    }
    else if (bt_getData->Text == "Stop") {                  
        bt_getData->Text = "Get Data";
    }

}
```

Then it will read the output using the OutputDataReceived EventHandler.
The problem is when I clicked the button again, the process will be Restarted, but the GUI can't read the new Output.

Case 1 : I cancelled the output read in the OutputDataReceived EventHandler then restart the process, but the next restarted process output can't be read.

```
private: System::Void outputData(System::Object^  sender, System::Diagnostics::DataReceivedEventArgs^  e) {                         
    x0 = xt;
    xt += 1;
    if (xt*x_scale > pb_Graph->Width) {
        x0 = 0;
        xt = 0;
        imgTemp = gcnew Bitmap(pb_Graph->Image, 460, 460);
        gpcGraph->Clear(Color::Transparent);
    }

    y0 = yt;
    yt = Convert::ToInt16(e->Data);
    ret_index++;
    if (ret_index > 2047) ret_index = 0;

    gpcGraph->DrawLine(greenPen,(float)x0*x_scale,pb_Graph->Height - (float)y0/y_scale - y_null,(float)xt*x_scale,pb_Graph->Height - (float)yt/y_scale - y_null);

    pb_Graph->Refresh();

}
```

After three times restart, this error shows :
    An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.dll

```
Additional information: An async read operation has already been started on the stream.
```

Case 2 : I didn't cancel the output read. The same error with case 1 shows, but it is still understandable to me.

Case 3 : I didn't redo the BeginOutputReadLine() when restarting. The error doesn't shown, but the restarted process output can't be read.

My actual goal is to restart the process periodically using a 1 mS timer, so I tested the restart process first using button. But it seems that the newly generated output can't be read.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: You probably didn't clean up your `process` object after the process exits. Please share the full code showing the whole lifetime of the `process` object.

Comment: Well... I'm not really sure what you've meant by "cleaning".

Comment: The full code for the child process itself is just this :

#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
 
 printf("0");
 
 }
 
}

I didn't call any parameters, such as process->Refresh() in the parent GUI

Comment: Sorry if I didn't make it clear. I'd like to see the full code for the _parent_ process.

Comment: I've edited the first post, to show the whole button process and the OutputDataReceived EventHandler, which is basically to plot line graph.
The process itself is first started at the Form_Load() Event, and the BeginOutputReadLine() is called there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay... I've managed to prevent the errors using different method, which is to call

```
process->StandardOutput->ReadLine();
```

This way the async stream reading won't happen.